# What does ro.debuggable=1 actually do?

Tags: android, adb, android-debug, streamline

I am trying to understand what the Android system property ro.debuggable actually does. I am using Arm Streamline to profile my android application and the documentation states that I can do application profiling using debuggable applications (applications built with the debuggable flag), or I can do a system-wide profile on a rooted device. Reading around I came across the ro.debuggable property and wondered if this would allow me to debug apps not built with the debuggable flag.

Best understanding I can glean so far from documentation is thet ro.debuggable=1 is usually the setting for eng and user-debug builds and somehow allows for a device to be rooted (though does not actually root a device), but what does it actually do? Does it *just* determine if a device can be rooted or not?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from the lifecycle of the Android application process:

1. Some application requests `system_server` to start an app to handle its request. For example, when a user clicks the WeChat icon on the launcher, the launcher requests `system_server` to start the WeChat application to respond to the user's request.
2. `system_server` resolves the request (actually the request Intent) and finally makes a decision to spawn a new process for WeChat to fulfill the request.
3. `system_server` calls [ProcessList.startProcess](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ProcessList.java;drc=9981aced5af430bf9b8a32485f7680ff04777995;l=2299) to spawn a new process to host WeChat. The process being spawned needs some basic information about the application it will run, such as `instruction-set`, `target-api`, UID, etc. One of the important pieces of information is whether the application is [debuggable](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ProcessList.java;drc=9981aced5af430bf9b8a32485f7680ff04777995;l=1839). `ProcessList` retrieves most of this information from `PackageManagerService`. For example, the debuggable option is set in the APK's manifest attribute `android:debuggable`.
4. `ProcessList` collects these options and forwards them to `ZygoteProcess`. `ZygoteProcess` writes these options to the `zygote` or `zygote64` process using a [Socket](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/ZygoteProcess.java;drc=acb493eaeb7d278324936956da48df9f3b7c4cb4;l=462).
5. `ZygoteServer` receives the socket request and processes it in [ZygoteConnection.processCommand](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/os/ZygoteConnection.java;drc=fab68e1481d8260e0b8c3e465ea8e2b5032a0cfe;l=123), parsing the buffer into `ZygoteArguments`.
6. Some default behaviors take effect on the parsed `ZygoteArguments`. For example, [applyDebuggerSystemProperty](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/os/Zygote.java;drc=e274a5ef062925c35b042726f9dff8c0fd6cabd6;l=1045). If this is an ENG build or USER_DEBUG build with `persist.debug.dalvik.vm.jdwp.enabled` set to 1, the debug options are enabled regardless of the options passed by `system_server` (the code in the main branch is slightly different from Android 13, which only takes into account the `ro.debuggable` property).
7. The newly spawned process uses the options to set up a JDWP server in [EnableDebugFeatures](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:art/runtime/native/dalvik_system_ZygoteHooks.cc;drc=ec4235e39765341a78c5596cff7e26865c648477;l=185), making the process present in DDMS and debuggable.

In summary, the `ro.debuggable` property has nothing to do with root access but is a property that affects the debug server of every app process in Android 13 (as explained above).